# Is it normal in React to use `useState` to manage whether a form has been submitted?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation

A basic online React tutorial is demonstrating how to create a React-based form with 3 fields (first name, last name, and email). Surprisingly to me, it has `useState` to manage whether or not a form has been submitted, which it uses to decide on whether to show a success message or not.

Please note that it does NOT make an actual form submission (i.e. no API calls) and so I am wondering whether it is using state only for simulation purposes here.

Here is a snippet:

```
const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
...
{submitted && !values.lastName && <span id='last-name-error'>Please enter a last name</span>}
...
{showSuccess && <div class='success-message'>Success! Thank you for registering</div>}
...
```

Is it normal for real-world React applications to `useState` to manage whether or not a simple form such as 'contact us' or 'feedback', etc, has been submitted? My guess is that normally there would be no need to do so.

As the resulting API call, whether 'success' or 'fail' could simply be used to show the state of the error message. Thereafter, the form should ideally reset itself to allow for another submission. So, there would be no need to store the state of the submitted form. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: In case anyone want to follow this tutorial: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/beginner-react-project-build-basic-forms-using-react-hooks/ , with code on [github](https://github.com/chrisblakely01/basic-react-forms)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing. basically if you want to store a data in React and this data has direct effect on your application you mostly should save it in state. When you submit a form, the form `onSubmit` event handler will be called and you can do everything in that event handler. It's clear that in the tutorial submitted state is a flag to simulate the fetch process. Usually when you want to handle submitting a form and fetching API you should store 2 items in state:

**Error and Loading**

You should use loading flag to show a loading indicator during fetching API and use error to check if any error exist store and show it. If API fetches successfully you may redirect user to another page, show a notification or change some data in your state. It's up to you. But be sure the `submitted` state in your tutorial is just an example ans simulation. But it has real usages in real world! Hope it helps!

Here is an example: I want to add a user by fetching an api and i want if api fetches successfully add it to the list:

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-framework-t1vce?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Any real-world examples that you can point me towards?

Comment: @Grateful Yeah! check out this simple sandbox [adding a user](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-framework-t1vce?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Appreciated. Thanks.